# where are set_facts stored for ansible when cacheable true?

Tags: ansible

I have an example playbook below. When I say cacheable: true where are facts stored? Also, how to delete these facts after for a fresh play? I have looked into the remote host(our example database) and found nothing and on the local host(where I ran my playbook) too cannot find it. I can see the facts displayed though. Found this on ansible docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/set_fact_module.html not much helpful to understand though.

```
 ---
 - name: Setting database facts 
   hosts: database_servers:!localhost
   tasks:
   - name: set_facts for database servers
       set_fact:
         database_endpoints:   "{{ remote_endpoints_dev }}"
         cacheable: true
       when: ENVIR == "dev"
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I say cacheable: true where are facts stored?

`cacheable` only takes effect if [fact caching](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) is enabled, and where the facts get stored depends on how you configured fact caching.

> Also, how to delete these facts after for a fresh play?

The facts will get updated every time the `set_fact` task runs. I use tags to control when those tasks run. You can control how long things stay in cache in the fact caching configuration.

Comment: thanks, it helped me very much! Does this store(cache) any facts on the remote hosts as well? or just on the machine(localhost) where we run the playbook?

Comment: The fact cache is only stored where you have configured Ansible to store it. E.g. on the machine where you run the script in a particular folder in json format, or in a redis database. It does not have a feature to store fact cache per host on every host separately.